# Specific standard measurements and info necessary for making a standard Shogi set (board and koma)

Tags: shogi

**Anything I figure out I will X out in the list of things I need. Solution will be at the bottom section named "RESULTS".**

I've been searching the Googles for a bit now, but I'm not able to find any (english) information on it. I'm planning on making my own board since I am in Mexico, and I can't find anyone selling a Shogi board around here.

Any answer that contains the details of your Shogi set is enough. Just remember, it has to be a genuine Japanese Shogi set, not plastic or anything like that. Basically if you could get these measurements from your personal Shogi set, I would really appreciate it.

So what are the standard measurements for a Shogi board?:

```
X Width (from black's perspective, left to right of board)
X Length (from black's perspective, top to bottom of board)
X Height (of entire board)
- Size of each square/space (where the piece will be put)
  - Width (from black's perspective, left to right of space)
  - Length (from black's perspective, top to bottom of space)
```

That's for the board, now I need for the individual pieces as follows, of course we're talking about if the piece was "standing up" in front of us:

```
X Height
X Width (widest point, bottom)
X Thickness (the whole piece)
X Degree angles
  X The angle from the bottom to the top (81 is the angle I believe)
  X The angle for the little "roof" of the top of the piece
```

Now, of course, these measurements are different from piece to piece, so the sizes are different, unless I put them on the same group, so you only need to find out the sizes of the pieces listed first:

```
x King
X Rook, Bishop
X Gold, Silver
X Knight
X Lance
X Pawn
```

Of course, I would also like the standard size for the komadais, in case there is a standard size. If there isn't, what's the normal average size for it?

These are all the measurements that I need in order to be able to make a full set. They should all be provided in mm/cm, because it's the most exact, and the measurement style used in Mexico.

Now, the calligraphy, of course. A full example of all the pieces in the "Kinki-Sho" calligraphy. Basically, an example of the calligraphy, how it should look, so that I can carve it to the wood. No pieces needed, only the calligraphy for each piece on a white background.

That is all the info I need, if you can provide necessary links I would highly appreciate it.

One last note, the website can be in Japanese, just be sure to provide some kind of translation, or give the info and the link as a reference.

---

**RESULTS**:

All the good references that I've found since opening this question:

- [THE MAKING (１５４）将棋盤ができるまで | サイエンス チャンネル](http://sciencechannel.jst.go.jp/B980601/detail/B030601154.html)
- [How to play Shogi(将棋) -Lesson#38- Shogi Board as Arts and Crafts - YouTube](http://youtu.be/h9zb5udfeWo)
- [How to play Shogi(将棋) -Lesson#39- Shogi Pieces as Arts and Crafts - YouTube](http://youtu.be/MF00nKgwNVU)
- [駒博士のＱ＆Ａ](http://www.tendocci.com/koma/qa.htm) and [What is the normal size of shogi pieces](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_normal_size_of_shogi_pieces)

Some things I might have figured out since opening this question:

All the sizes, measurements, specifications, angles etc. I have figured out can be found in this private Gist: https://gist.github.com/3763b7d9d5c1d6a4916f

Comment: Wait, I just noticed, why don't you put the results in an answer? They should be there! I thought it was part of the question. :)

Comment: @Alenanno I planned on putting it in an answer. But it's not yet complete, I'm not sure of the measurements. However, what I've gathered can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Greduan/3763b7d9d5c1d6a4916f

Comment: @Eduan - Putting your work in progress in an answer certainly makes more sense than putting it in the question.

Comment: @ire_and_curses You're right, I put the Gist in an answer. :)

Comment: on the front view, what would be the angle on the top, did you not post that measure or is it my mistake? thanks in advance

Comment: Cybot could you provide more details of what you mean? I'm afraid I don't understand. :/ You mean viewing a piece from the front as if it was standing up? If that were the case, do you mean the angle from the bottom to the top or the little arrow shape that it has at the top?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally! This answer is now complete! I know all the measurements now! And they all fit, I made sure. You can find the measurements in this [private Gist](https://gist.github.com/Greduan/3763b7d9d5c1d6a4916f) (meaning you can only access it if you have the link).

Here's a full copy of the Gist, no changes made to it:

```
This is a related question in boardgames.stackexchange.com:
http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/10836/4779

===============================================================================
The measurements for the board:

Length . 33.66cm
Width .. 33.33cm
Height . 30.3mm

Measurements for the squares in the board:

Length . 36mm
Width .. 33mm

===============================================================================
The amount of pieces that I will manufacture:

King ........... 2
Rook ........... 2
Bishop ......... 2
Gold General ... 4
Silver General . 4
Knight ......... 4
Lance .......... 4
Pawn ........... 19

===============================================================================
The exact measurements for each piece.
Measurements provided in this order:

Height, width (bottom), thickness, angle (general, bottom > top),
angle (thickness, bottom > top).

King ......................... 32mm 28.7mm 9.7mm  81° 85°
Rook, Bishop ................. 31mm 27.7mm 9.3mm  81° 85°
Gold General, Silver General . 30mm 26.7mm 8.8mm  81° 85°
Knight ....................... 29mm 25.5mm 8.3mm  81° 85°
Lance ........................ 28mm 23.5mm 8.0mm  81° 85°
Pawn ......................... 27mm 22.5mm 7.75mm 81° 85°
```

Be sure to understand this is not perfect yet. It's not 100% ready yet. Probably... You can use these numbers and get a working set. But I'm still refining them to perfection.

Comment: I don't understand the 85° angle, where is this?

Comment: @mart As I see it, it is one of two things (bear with my memory :) ), it is the angle to make the arrow shape. OR, if the piece was laying flat, the angle of the cut (because when the piece is laying flat, the top surface is not parallel to the bottom surface). Honestly not sure which one it is.

Comment: For those trying to make their own pieces, I was able to determine all the measurements needed. You can view the OpenScad file with the measurements here:
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4761632